# Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields''

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have written mongo db query like

```
            $outputTotalResults= $this->db->studentTbl->aggregate(
           array(
           array(
             '$addFields' => array(
             'weight' => array(
             '$cond' => array(
              array( 
                   '$or' => array( 
                        array( 
                          '$eq' => array( 
                           array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$middle_name', ' ', '$last_name')),
                           $arg
                           )
                      ),
                array( 
                     '$eq' => array(
                       array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$middle_name')), 
                        $arg 
                         )
                     ),
                 array(
                    '$eq' => array(
                     array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$last_name')),
                      $arg 
                      )
                    )
                   )
                 ),
                 10,
                  0
                 )
               )
              )
             ),
             array(
                   '$sort' => array( 'weight'=> -1 )
                 )
             )
           );
```

I am trying to sort the students. The above code is throwing error "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields''"

Please help me !!!

Comment: It's been added in v3.4. Please confirm your `db.version().

Comment: I have 3.2.2 mongodb installed and also tell me whether $addFeild will alter document structure in database or not.

Comment: Upgrade the db then.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your mongodb version. This feature is not available on 3.2, it's been added in v3.4. [Upgrade the db then](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-update-mongodb-from-3-2-to-3-4-10).